# How to check if Facebook is installed Android

Tags: android, facebook, package

I am modifying my app to be able to catch if a user tries to publish without having the facebook app installed (required for SSO).  Here is the code I am using:

```
try{
    ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().
            getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.android", 0 );
    return true;
} catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
    return false;
}
```

The problem is, it is always catching an error.  According to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323553/way-to-know-if-my-application-is-installed), I need to request the appropriate permission but I don't know what permissions I need to request.

Is my problem a permission one or something else?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`com.facebook.android` is the package name for the Facebook SDK. The Facebook app's package is `com.facebook.katana`.

Comment: if you're interested in a convenient way to check the package names of other apps on your device, I found this app helpful: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi&hl=en_GB

Comment: @hmac the link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 12):

To check whether or not an app is installed on Android use this method:

```
public static boolean isPackageInstalled(Context c, String targetPackage) {
    PackageManager pm = c.getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(targetPackage, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In your case use any of these packages:

- com.facebook.orca
- com.facebook.katana
- com.example.facebook
- com.facebook.android

```
boolean hasPackage = isPackageInstalled(MainActivity.this, "com.facebook.katana");
```

- For Kotlin

  ```
    fun isPackageInstalled(packageName: String, context: Context): Boolean {
       return try {
                val packageManager = context.packageManager
                packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
                true
            } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
                false
            }
        }
  ```

Answer (score 6):

You can check it for all Facebook Apps that any of Facebook apps are installed or not .
For supporting OS level 11 we need to add this in `AndrodiManifest.xml` to avoid package name not found exception -

```
<manifest ...
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
    <package android:name="com.facebook.lite" />
    <package android:name="com.facebook.android" />
    <package android:name="com.example.facebook" />
</queries>
 <application .....
```

Then add this method to you code  -

```
public static String isFacebookAppInstalled(Context context){

        if(context!=null) {
            PackageManager pm=context.getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;

            //First check that if the main app of facebook is installed or not
            try {
                applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
                return applicationInfo.enabled?"com.facebook.katana":"";
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }

            //Then check that if the facebook lite is installed or not
            try {
                applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.lite", 0);
                return applicationInfo.enabled?"com.facebook.lite":"";
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }

            //Then check the other facebook app using different package name is installed or not
            try {
                applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.android", 0);
                return applicationInfo.enabled?"com.facebook.android":"";
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }

            try {
                applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.example.facebook", 0);
                return applicationInfo.enabled?"com.example.facebook":"";
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

And then launch the app -

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(isFacebookAppInstalled(context))) {
 /* Facebook App is installed,So launch it. 
  It will return you installed facebook app's package
  name which will be useful to launch the app */

  Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + yourURL);
 Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(isFacebookAppInstalled(context);
                if (intent != null) {
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    Intent intentForOtherApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    context.startActivity(intentForOtherApp);
                } 
 }
```

Comment: adding manifest to queries is  works

Answer (score 4):

```
 if (isAppInstalled()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "facebook app already installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "facebook app not installing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



public boolean isAppInstalled() {
            try {
                getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
                return true;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the function in Utilities or anywhere suit for you.This will function will help you to check any app installed or not.let me say for myself it is in Utilities.java

```
public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
        try {
            context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then, Call this function from anywhere. for eg to check facebook app

```
if(Utilities.isAppInstalled(getApplicationContext(), "com.facebook.katana")) {
                    // Do something
                }else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana"));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
```

**Enjoy**

Answer (score 0):

Best Approach is to pick the package name including com.facebook but anyway you may use following packages:

- com.facebook.orca
- com.facebook.katana
- com.example.facebook
- com.facebook.android

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana"));
startActivity(i);
```

this code worked for me

Comment: answer not relevant to the question. He was asking something else.

Comment: Please read carefully before answering to the question. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isAppInstalled()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "facebook app already installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "facebook app not installing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

public boolean isAppInstalled() {
            try {
                getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
                return true;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Posting code without formatting or explanation is kind of bad!

Answer (score -1):

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e("tag","url override url  = "+ url);

            if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity( intent );

            return true;
        }





    });
```