# How do I check the facebook app is installed in my device or not programmatically

Tags: android

I created an android photo app and in which I add the functionality of image sharing on facebook,twitter,instagram using intent but when I share the image the app crashes if the facebook,twitter,instagram app was not installed on device.

Comment: hint : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711295/how-to-check-if-facebook-is-installed-android

Answer (score 6):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-if-the-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android-programmatically) question.It will give you what you want.Just replace the package name with **com.facebook.android** OR **com.facebook.katana**

The code:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //Put the package name here...
        boolean installed  =   appInstalledOrNot("com.Ch.Example.pack");  
        if(installed) {
            //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
            Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");//if this name does not work provide the other one
            startActivity(LaunchIntent);

            System.out.println("App already installed on your phone");        
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("App is not installed on your phone");
        }
    }

    private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed = false;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed ;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. only "com.facebook.katana" worked for me

Comment: does the appInstalledOrNot() approach require any permissions?