# Android check if facebook is preinstalled or not?

Tags: android

I have added one code to check if Facebook installed or not, in normal cases it is working but when facebook comes by default on some devices it is not working, it says package not found. can anyone help me here?

```
public Boolean checkFbInstalled() {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            flag = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (flag == false) {
            try {
                pm.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.lite", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                flag = true;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                flag = false;
            }
        }

        if (flag == false) {
            try {
                pm.getPackageGids("com.facebook.katana");
                flag = true;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: Not Sure Tre [These](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39658767/4168607)  packages.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the facebook package name exist with `try-catch`:

```
try{
    ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().
            getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0 );
    return true;
}catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
    return false;
}
```

Note: If you like to see if the Facebook **SDK** exist and not the Facebook app you need to change the package name on the `getApplicationInfo()` method from `com.facebook.katana` to `com.facebook.android`

Comment: not working, normal situations this code is working, but when Facebook comes by default in mobile it is not working, it always gives namenotfoundexception only