# Launch Social Media App or browser from another Activity (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent

Currently when user click the button , they will directly launch the Facebook and Twitter app. However I want to let user able to choose use browser or application to view the profile.
Another problem is I can't find Instagram Protocol to launch the app to view the profile, I only can view on webpage. Anyone Got Idea?

```
        btnFb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri = "fb://page/80829078894";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    btnTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri = "twitter://user?user_id=87114940";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    btnInstagram.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri = "http://instagram.com/plaza_semanggi";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to the following

```
    btnFb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            openFacebookIntent(ActivityMain.this, "80829078894");


        }
    });

    btnTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            openTwiterIntent(ActivityMain.this, "87114940");

        }
    });

    btnInstagram.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            openInstagramIntent(ActivityMain.this, "plaza_semanggi");

        }
    });
```

And had the following methods.

```
public static void openFacebookIntent(Context context, String facebookID) {

    Intent intent;

    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/facebookID"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/facebookID"));
    }

    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public static void openTwiterIntent(Context context, String twitterID) {

    Intent intent;

    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=twitterID"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/twitterID"));
    }

    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public static void openInstagramIntent(Context context, String instagramID) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/instagramID");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    intent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/instagramID")));
    }
}
```

Check if the facebook is installed.

```
private boolean isAppInstalled(String uri)
{
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try
    {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed ;
}

boolean appInstalled = isAppInstalled("com.facebook.katana");
```

credits to [Find out if app is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373135/find-out-if-app-is-installed)

Comment: Hi, it's work well. However, possible to give option for user to choose web browser or app instead of directly launch the app ?

Comment: That unusual, but you can check if the app is installed with the method I had to the answer, and let the user choose to open the app or the browser.