# hook between downloading and installing application from android market

Tags: android, installation

I need to make an antivirus type thing... for which i want that after downloading and before installing the application i want to check it... how can that be possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510544/android-how-to-intercept-the-install-application-intent). You can determine that an app has been installed, but not intervene, within the Android security model (unrooted devices).

Perhaps Google is planning on enabling a more antimalware-friendly API in the future: however, anything that is permitted to do what traditional antivirus packages comes dangerously close to rootkit territory...

Comment: hmmmm.... m quite satisfied with the answer but how does traditional antivirus programs scans the application before installing...

Comment: Do any Android antimalware scan **before** install? I haven't seen any make that claim -- and I won't necessarily believe their claims unless they also root the phone...