# How to implement a changelog in android?

Tags: android, changelog

for my app i want to implement a changelog, but dont know how (which concept).

I want, that the changelog pops up once a time after new version of my app installed.
Sounds easy, but i have no clue. :/

Dialog to show my Changelog exists already, i just wanna know how to show it one after an update.

Thanks for your hints.

Prexx

Comment: Conside the intent of the package_add http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510544/android-how-to-intercept-the-install-application-intent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

one option is to use Android Change Log.

> With Android Change Log you can easily create, show and maintain an
>   Android change log dialog.

**Features**

- display only what's new or show the whole change log
- display on first start of newly installed app or on new app version
- write the change log in a simplified language but also use HTML and
  CSS if needed

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: There is no link

Comment: Is it this? https://github.com/koem/android-change-log (I searched on the website for "android change log" and I found one result on the site: https://petoria.de/changelog-fuer-android-app-erstellen/ which had a link that directed to that link)

Answer (score 7):

You can store a value in `SharedPreferences` which version you showed the changelog last time.

E.g.: `'lastChangelogVersion' : '1.1.0'`

When your `MainActivity` starts it compares this value with the current version of your software and if it differs the changelog popup appears (and sets the new value).

This value will not be overridden when a new version of your application is being installed.

**UPDATE:**

Also, you might encounter that the user cleared your application's data. In this case you can't decide whether the changelog was displayed before or not so you can show it again. Android Market works the same way: if you clear it's app data you will be facing with the Licence Agreement again when launching Market.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following options for adding a changelog to your Android app. Using any of these libraries would definitely save time over implementing this yourself. They all follow the general approach that @papaiatis mentions in his answer.

1. [changeloglib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/changeloglib)
2. [ckChangeLog](https://github.com/cketti/ckChangeLog)
3. [paperboy](https://github.com/porokoro/paperboy)
4. [changelog](https://github.com/MFlisar/changelog)
5. [android-change-log](https://github.com/koem/android-change-log)
6. [Appnouncements](https://github.com/Appnouncements/appnouncements-android) (Disclaimer: I'm the author of this one)

Comment: PLEASE NOTE that AppNouncements is currently a broken link until edited.

Answer (score 2):

I found Michael Flisar's change log (https://github.com/MFlisar/changelog) *extremely* easy to use.

After an app update I show a "What's New" dialog by:

```
ChangelogBuilder builder = new ChangelogBuilder()
            .withTitle("What\'s New")
            .withUseBulletList(true)
            .withManagedShowOnStart(true)
            .buildAndShowDialog(activity, false);
```

And I can show an activity with the entire change log via:

```
ChangelogBuilder builder = new ChangelogBuilder()
            .withTitle("Change Log")
            .withUseBulletList(true)
            .buildAndStartActivity(context, true);
```

Easy peasy.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Copyright (C) 2011-2013, Karsten Priegnitz
 *
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this piece of software
 * for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that
 * the above copyright notice and this permission notice appear in the
 * source code of all copies.
 *
 * It would be appreciated if you mention the author in your change log,
 * contributors list or the like.
 *
 * @author: Karsten Priegnitz
 * @see: http://code.google.com/p/android-change-log/
 */
package sheetrock.panda.changelog;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class ChangeLog {

    private final Context context;
    private String lastVersion, thisVersion;

    // this is the key for storing the version name in SharedPreferences
    private static final String VERSION_KEY = "PREFS_VERSION_KEY";

    private static final String NO_VERSION = "";

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Retrieves the version names and stores the new version name in SharedPreferences
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public ChangeLog(Context context) {
        this(context, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context));
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Retrieves the version names and stores the new version name in SharedPreferences
     *
     * @param context
     * @param sp
     *            the shared preferences to store the last version name into
     */
    public ChangeLog(Context context, SharedPreferences sp) {
        this.context = context;

        // get version numbers
        this.lastVersion = sp.getString(VERSION_KEY, NO_VERSION);
        Log.d(TAG, "lastVersion: " + lastVersion);
        try {
            this.thisVersion = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),
                    0).versionName;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            this.thisVersion = NO_VERSION;
            Log.e(TAG, "could not get version name from manifest!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "appVersion: " + this.thisVersion);
    }

    /**
     * @return The version name of the last installation of this app (as described in the former
     *         manifest). This will be the same as returned by <code>getThisVersion()</code> the
     *         second time this version of the app is launched (more precisely: the second time
     *         ChangeLog is instantiated).
     * @see AndroidManifest.xml#android:versionName
     */
    public String getLastVersion() {
        return this.lastVersion;
    }

    /**
     * @return The version name of this app as described in the manifest.
     * @see AndroidManifest.xml#android:versionName
     */
    public String getThisVersion() {
        return this.thisVersion;
    }

    /**
     * @return <code>true</code> if this version of your app is started the first time
     */
    public boolean firstRun() {
        return !this.lastVersion.equals(this.thisVersion);
    }

    /**
     * @return <code>true</code> if your app including ChangeLog is started the first time ever.
     *         Also <code>true</code> if your app was deinstalled and installed again.
     */
    public boolean firstRunEver() {
        return NO_VERSION.equals(this.lastVersion);
    }

    /**
     * @return An AlertDialog displaying the changes since the previous installed version of your
     *         app (what's new). But when this is the first run of your app including ChangeLog then
     *         the full log dialog is show.
     */
    public AlertDialog getLogDialog() {
        return this.getDialog(this.firstRunEver());
    }

    /**
     * @return an AlertDialog with a full change log displayed
     */
    public AlertDialog getFullLogDialog() {
        return this.getDialog(true);
    }

    protected AlertDialog getDialog(boolean full) {
        WebView wv = new WebView(this.context);

        wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(context.getResources().getString(
                R.string.background_color)));
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, this.getLog(full), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this.context,
                android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
        builder.setTitle(
                context.getResources().getString(
                        full ? R.string.changelog_full_title : R.string.changelog_title))
                .setView(wv)
                .setCancelable(false)
                // OK button
                .setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.changelog_ok_button),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                updateVersionInPreferences();
                            }
                        });

        if (!full) {
            // "more ..." button
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.changelog_show_full,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            getFullLogDialog().show();
                        }
                    });
        }

        return builder.create();
    }

    protected void updateVersionInPreferences() {
        // save new version number to preferences
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString(VERSION_KEY, thisVersion);
        // // on SDK-Versions > 9 you should use this:
        // if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        // editor.commit();
        // } else {
        // editor.apply();
        // }
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * @return HTML displaying the changes since the previous installed version of your app (what's
     *         new)
     */
    public String getLog() {
        return this.getLog(false);
    }

    /**
     * @return HTML which displays full change log
     */
    public String getFullLog() {
        return this.getLog(true);
    }

    /** modes for HTML-Lists (bullet, numbered) */
    private enum Listmode {
        NONE, ORDERED, UNORDERED,
    };

    private Listmode listMode = Listmode.NONE;
    private StringBuffer sb = null;
    private static final String EOCL = "END_OF_CHANGE_LOG";

    protected String getLog(boolean full) {
        // read changelog.txt file
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            InputStream ins = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.changelog);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));

            String line = null;
            boolean advanceToEOVS = false; // if true: ignore further version
                                           // sections
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.trim();
                char marker = line.length() > 0 ? line.charAt(0) : 0;
                if (marker == '$') {
                    // begin of a version section
                    this.closeList();
                    String version = line.substring(1).trim();
                    // stop output?
                    if (!full) {
                        if (this.lastVersion.equals(version)) {
                            advanceToEOVS = true;
                        } else if (version.equals(EOCL)) {
                            advanceToEOVS = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (!advanceToEOVS) {
                    switch (marker) {
                    case '%':
                        // line contains version title
                        this.closeList();
                        sb.append("<div class='title'>" + line.substring(1).trim() + "</div>\n");
                        break;
                    case '_':
                        // line contains version title
                        this.closeList();
                        sb.append("<div class='subtitle'>" + line.substring(1).trim() + "</div>\n");
                        break;
                    case '!':
                        // line contains free text
                        this.closeList();
                        sb.append("<div class='freetext'>" + line.substring(1).trim() + "</div>\n");
                        break;
                    case '#':
                        // line contains numbered list item
                        this.openList(Listmode.ORDERED);
                        sb.append("<li>" + line.substring(1).trim() + "</li>\n");
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        // line contains bullet list item
                        this.openList(Listmode.UNORDERED);
                        sb.append("<li>" + line.substring(1).trim() + "</li>\n");
                        break;
                    default:
                        // no special character: just use line as is
                        this.closeList();
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            this.closeList();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    protected void openList(Listmode listMode) {
        if (this.listMode != listMode) {
            closeList();
            if (listMode == Listmode.ORDERED) {
                sb.append("<div class='list'><ol>\n");
            } else if (listMode == Listmode.UNORDERED) {
                sb.append("<div class='list'><ul>\n");
            }
            this.listMode = listMode;
        }
    }

    protected void closeList() {
        if (this.listMode == Listmode.ORDERED) {
            sb.append("</ol></div>\n");
        } else if (this.listMode == Listmode.UNORDERED) {
            sb.append("</ul></div>\n");
        }
        this.listMode = Listmode.NONE;
    }

    private static final String TAG = "ChangeLog";

    /**
     * manually set the last version name - for testing purposes only
     *
     * @param lastVersion
     */
    public void dontuseSetLastVersion(String lastVersion) {
        this.lastVersion = lastVersion;
    }
}
```