# Android: detect apk install prompt has done installing

Tags: android, listview, android-install-apk

My app is searching apks over SMB protocol and create a list of installed/installable/updateable applications (if packagename equals with my applications packagename). If the user make a click on an item to install/update the intallation prompt appears and i would like to refresh the list if an app was installed or updated. How can i earn that?

I have tried to search similar questions this and other sites, sorry if that question is a duplicate.

Thanks for helpin me out.

Comment: Listen for `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` broadcasts.

Comment: The answer to this question is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510544/android-how-to-intercept-the-install-application-intent

Comment: @CommonsWare you lead me to the solution, if you would like to write it as answer i would mark it as accepted. :)